# Mysql query prerared but not executed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I need to find bug in my code but I can't figure out what is wrong
query is preparing without problem and when executing is not working at all
I always get "Not executed"

```
$query="INSERT INTO users (firstname,lastname,username,mail,password,user_ip,phone,premium,blocked) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    
    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->bind_param("ssssssiii",$firstname,$lastname,$username,$mail,$pass,$ip,$phone,$premium,$blocked);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
          header("Location:complete.php");
          exit();
        }else{
          echo "Not executed";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Not prepared";
    }
```

Comment: Obtain complete error message text provided by SQL server.

Comment: Please provide the CREATE TABLE statement for this table

Comment: @Akina I tried trigger_error($conn->error); but it shows nothing

Comment: Check `$stmt->error` - the error occures during statement execution, there is no problem with the connection...

Comment: @Akina also $stmt->error show nothing